# Using Matlab 2017 .Net DLL in Visual Studio 2017 Exception Unhandled

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to develop a `C#.Net` console application in `Visual Studio 2017` .
So I compiled with `Matlab Library Compiler` some code in `Matlab 2017` then make `DLL` for `Visual Studio 2017`.
When I run there is no error but I get this Exception:

`Exception Unhandled :System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Trial.CSharpClass' threw an exception.'`

I use `MWArray.dll` as reference at this address:

```
F:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\dotnetbuilder\bin\win64\v4.0\MWArray.dll
```

and also `Trial.dll`.

Here is my `Matlab` `addNumbers.m` Code:

```
function output = addNumbers( num1 ,num2 )

output = num1+num2;

end
```

Here is my `Test.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using Trial;

namespace MatlabAndCSharpTrial
{
    class Test
    {
        public static void addNumbers()
        {
            double num1 = 5;
            double num2 = 9;

            CSharpClass obj = new CSharpClass();    // Exception Unhandled is Here

            MWArray output = obj.addNumbers((MWArray)num1, (MWArray)num2);
            Console.WriteLine("Output ==> \n"+output);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

and my `program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MatlabAndCSharpTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test.addNumbers();
        }
    }
}
```

So I used this project on `Matlab 2010` and `Visual Studio 2010` and works **successfully** also I try `x64` and `x86` in `Visual Studio 2017` problem is still available.
So what should I do?

**EDIT:**
As I replace :

```
CSharpClass obj = new CSharpClass();    
MWArray output = obj.addNumbers((MWArray)num1, (MWArray)num2);
```

with:

```
MWArray output = CSharpClass.addNumbers((MWArray)num1, (MWArray)num2);
```

I get this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CSharpClass.addNumbers(MWArray, MWArray)'
```

Comment: There's an unhandled exception being thrown in the constructor (or static constructor) of `Class1`, so [edit] your question to include that

Comment: I do not have access inside of  the constructor , it has been compiled by Matlab Compiler into a DLL.

Comment: Ok... since the most obvious problem was discarded, let's try with this: your Windows is x86 or x64? Your Matlab is 32 or 64 bits? Your VS project is 32 or 64 bits? It seems like this is the most common cause of this problem with stand alone libraries in Matlab.

Comment: All of them are 64bit (x64)

Comment: I edited my question , and tested both status.no one works.

Comment: As I tested in Matlab 2010-VS 2010  successfully maybe Matlab 2017 with VS 2017, and Matlab 2015 with VS 2015 in using DLLs are incompatible or must use with special coding structure.

Comment: As I was typing in the other question before you deleted it: you're not giving the full MATLAB version number. Are you using R2017a or R2017b? The latter version [officially lists MSCV 2017 as a supported compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2017b_SupportedCompilers.pdf). But in my experience there is no reason not to use a newer compiler than what is officially supported.

Comment: I use Matlab R2017b